# Adjust System Clock to NTP

Tags: debian, xfce, ntp

Recently installed Debian 10 "Buster" at an old computer here and now it's showing `$ date` output with 1 hour less.

How could be sycronized system time with NTP GMT -3, America/Recife timezone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To verify the timezone of your system (mine is Europe/Berlin), run

```
$ cat /etc/timezone
Europe/Berlin
```

If it is wrong, run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

and choose `America`, then `Recife` and check if the printed local time is now correct.

You can also print the UTC date with

```
date -u
```

which should be your local time +3 hours.

Comment: Is this `tzdata` synchronized with some sort of online clock or just with hardware clock? Looks like it doesn't works alongside with `NTP`.

Comment: The synchronization is usually done by [systemd-timesyncd](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/systemd/systemd-timesyncd.8.en.html) or [ntpd](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/ntp/ntpd.8.en.html) or manually. The timezone itself is just static information. You can show the status of your system clock (RTC stores local time or universal time) and status of systemd-timesyncd.service with `timedatectl`. Use `timedatectl set-ntp true` to enable synchronization.

Comment: The `timedatectl set-ntp true` isn't working.

Comment: Had to remove `ntp` and `ntpdate`, then `$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`, which enabled NTP in $ datetimectl` output.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do so using ntp or ntpdate.

```
apt install ntpdate
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

ntpdate is mostly useful for one-time synchronizations.
Whereas the ntp daemon would run in background, and keep your clock up to date:

```
apt install ntp
cat <<EOF >/etc/ntp.conf
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
server pool.ntp.org
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
EOF
systemctl start ntp
systemctl enable ntp
```

Though you might just be using the wrong timezone. Some GMT-3 example:

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires /etc/localtime
```

Comment: Tried it, but conflicted with `tzdata`, which is the default package that manages date and time in Debian 10 "Buster". Solved it justly removing `ntp` and `ntpdate`, then `$ sudo dpkg reconfigure tzdata`, which enabled `NET service` in `$ timedatectl` output. And yes, `tzdata` is online synchronized with NTP.

Answer (score 4):

If the time difference is exactly one hour, it's most likely not a time issue, but a time zone issue.

Maybe you don't need ntp, you just need to set the right time zone.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/544657/set-time-zone-without-root-privilege/544658#544658) might help.

Comment: The `tzdata` package automatically manages date, time and NTP in Debian 10 "Buster".